# How can I convince my instructor to allow me to self-study?

Tags: independent-study

Last month, I took an extra Chemistry class and since then I had to attend the extra classes after my college ends. But However, I have already self-studied advanced chemistry by myself and For me, The Chemistry Class I am taking is a waste of time because it teaches the same things that I have already leant before. However, The Instructor of that Extra Chemistry class is the same person who is my Lecturer and grader of my College class. That means, if I leave the Extra Chemistry Class then It will affect my college grades. So, Is there any way, to convince my instructor that I want to leave that extra chemistry class and self study by myself without affecting my college grades ?

Comment: I don't understand why leaving the extra class is going to affect your grades in the college class? Is this instructor known to be vindictive?

Comment: Actually, the Instructor had advised me to attend his Extra Classes to improve my grades and It seems very odd to leave his extra class by disobeying his advice.

Comment: If you've studied the material in the class before, and this is an "extra" class, which I assume means its not part of core requirements, what are you gaining by taking the class at all?

Comment: You should go back over what you've written. In the first sentence only . . . (1) Classes typically last more than a month, so "Last month I took" doesn't make sense. Maybe the end of the class occurred sometime within the past month? (2) *I had to attend the extra classes* -- Do you mean "some extra classes? At this point there has been no mention of extra classes. (3) Are the extra classes in chemistry or just additional classes needed for some graduation requirement? (4) *my college ends* -- Do you mean the end of your degree program or the end of the college's most recent semester/quarter?

Comment: Just I want to clarify that, The Extra Classes are Intended to revise the core materials for my college chemistry classes. My College Lecturer advised me to take his Extra Chemistry classes to improve my grade in my College's core chemistry class. Hope you all understand.

Comment: So the extra classes are remedial/revision classes for the main course, rather than more advanced topics than the main course? And your instructor advised you to attend the extra classes because of your poor grades? Have you explained to the instructor that you have studied more advanced topics and feel the extra class is a waste of time? What did they say?

Comment: @astronat  Yes, I have already told him about this but he advised me to take the Extra for better revision so that I can do well in my upcoming exams. Now, How can I disobey him by leaving those extra classes ?

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you just have to comply with the instructor's wishes and do what is asked. Words are probably not going to convince them.

But, if you really want to convince them that you know the material, ask them to give you an exam, perhaps an oral exam, on the required material. If you do well, then they may be convinced. But if not, then you have the information you need that you really aren't ready.

An oral exam need only take 10 or 15 minutes, actually. Either you struggle or you excel. It can become obvious quickly which "bin" you fall in to.